# Comparing column value count in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called `Orders`. It has columns `id`, `orderid`, `qty`, `cost`, `location`, `currency`...etc.

I have to insert values from this order table into another table for a given `order id`, but the problem is in `currency`.

For each `orderid` there will be multiple rows in the `order` table and each row can have difference `currency`.

So while inserting a new row from this table for a `orderid`, I need to get count of the distinct currencies and insert the currency which has the highest count.

How can I compare count of distinct values in a column? This is in SQL Server.

Comment: do you have a field that indicates what currency you are dealing with? you should probably share the table schema too

Comment: Are you saying you have multiple orders with the same orderid? That will cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: I have multiple items for same order with same order id...and each item will have multiple currencies...

Eg : 

ID OrderId Currency Cost
1    10        USD     1000
2    10        EUR     522
3    10        USD       999
4    10        INR     999

Here since USD comes more ...i want to get tht, i need to use it inside another insert statement

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as
(
select orderid,currency, row_number() over
    (partition by orderid,currency order by orderid,currency) rownumber
  from orders 
)  

select cte.orderid,cte.currency 
from cte
join
(select orderid,max(rownumber) rownumber2
  from cte group by orderid) A
on cte.orderid=a.orderid and cte.rownumber=a.rownumber2
```

Demo on SQLFIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c046/25

Thanks to bluefeet for sample data

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are not exactly clear but it seems like you might be able to use something like this:

```
select o.id,
  o.orderid,
  o.currency,
  o.cost
from orders o
inner join
(
  select orderid, currency,
    CountCurrency,
    max(CountCurrency) over(partition by orderid) mx
  from
  (
    select orderid, currency, count(currency) CountCurrency
    from orders
    group by orderid, currency
  ) o
) m
  on o.orderid = m.orderid
  and o.currency = m.currency
where m.CountCurrency = m.mx
order by o.orderid, o.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40f3f/2)

This returns all rows that contain the currency that appear most by `orderid`. Using the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
    ([id] int, [orderid] int, [currency] varchar(3), [cost] int)
;

INSERT INTO orders
    ([id], [orderid], [currency], [cost])
VALUES
    (1, 10, 'USD', 1000),
    (2, 10, 'EUR', 522),
    (3, 10, 'USD', 999),
    (4, 10, 'INR', 999),
    (5, 20, 'TST', 557),
    (6, 25, 'GRB', 24),
    (7, 20, 'TST', 78),
    (8, 30, 'HYT', 3)
;
```

The result is:

```
| ID | ORDERID | CURRENCY | COST |
----------------------------------
|  1 |      10 |      USD | 1000 |
|  3 |      10 |      USD |  999 |
|  5 |      20 |      TST |  557 |
|  7 |      20 |      TST |   78 |
|  6 |      25 |      GRB |   24 |
|  8 |      30 |      HYT |    3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are trying to find the currency with the most records in the `Orders` table given a specific `OrderId`?

Something like this -- it could return multiple records if multiple currencies are represented with the same count?

```
SELECT MAX(c.CurrencyCount), c.currency
FROM 
(
    SELECT currency, Count(currency) as CurrencyCount
    FROM Orders
    WHERE OrderId = 12345
    GROUP BY currency
) c
GROUP BY c.currency
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, do you want to migrate the row from Orders to otherTable including two more columns: maxCurrency and totalDistinctCurrency.

If my understood is right, so you can do like this:

```
INSERT INTO otherTable(
  maxCurrency, 
  totalDistinctCurrency, 
  otherColsFromOrders) 
SELECT 
  MAX(currency), 
  COUNT(DISTINCT currency), 
  * 
FROM Orders  
WHERE orderid = SOME_ORDER_ID_YOU_WANT;
```

Pay attention in two points:

1. You might change the SOME_ORDER_ID_YOU_WANT by the **orderid** you want;
2. You might change the **otherColsFromOrders** to the names of the corresponding columns in  otherTable that will match the order of the columns in the Orders table, because of the * when selecting.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

One more options

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders t
WHERE EXISTS(
             SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(COUNT(t2.currency)) OVER() = COUNT(t2.currency) THEN t2.currency END
             FROM Orders t2             
             WHERE t2.orderid = t.orderid            
             GROUP BY t2.currency
             INTERSECT
             SELECT t.currency
             )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9463a/1/0)